# Removing summoned ender dragon (Minecraft.)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I summoned an ender dragon in minecraft realms (in the overworld) and it just sits there and makes a lot of noise. I have tried many things to remove it but it will not work. (Cheats are on!) It does not move or shoot fireballs it just makes a lot of noise and stays in one place. Please someone help me I really need to remove this...

Comment: @Molley Jones could you please tell us what you've done so far to try to fix the problem? It's hard to tell you an answer if we don't know that you have tried what we are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

First, Please provide more information next time, which will aid us in helping you - Such as what you have tried, or game specs - modded etc.

This is intended behavior in the game, because the dragon's code causes it to go to 0,0 - Like in the enderdragon fight. - Detailed Here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-95601

Since you have not told us what you have done, Here are a few things you can try -

Try and kill it manually, with a sword.

You could also try

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:ender_dragon]
```

Please let us know if neither of these work, or if you require more help.

Comment: None of those work, and i'm sorry i did not provide much information, i thought people would know you can't mod realms, and if I had cheats on, i would be able to change game specs, and that you can't kill it with a sword. Sorry I just assumed people that read what i wrote would know.

Comment: Hi Molly,
I said modded as an example. Game specs cannot be altered by having cheats on or off, so I don't see how that could affect it.

Seeing that you have tried killing ender_dragon, the other possible command is ` /kill @e[type=!Player].` Be aware it will kill ALL entities except for the player, INCLUDING boats itemframes, villagers, minecarts and other. This command will kill any bugged out entities as well. 

Please ensure you have run both kill commands. (ender_dragon) (!player)